# How to update jqx grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
             url: "RequestHandler?usercommand=showcriticaldatezone&useraction=ShowUserPreferenceDashbord_frm&subCommand=criticaldatezone",
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: dateText,
             contentType: 'application/json',
             async:'false',
             cache:'false',

             success: function (data) {                     
                var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);
                var tempdate;
                alert("parse json  - "+parsedJSON.length);
                js= [];

                 for (var i=0;i<parsedJSON.length;i++) {
                  alert(" critical date is -:"+parsedJSON[i].CriticalDate);
                  js.push(parsedJSON[i].CriticalDate);
                //tempdate='{"Date":['+'"'+ parsedJSON[i].CriticalDate + '"' + ']}';
                }
                tempdate='{"Date":'+JSON.stringify(js)+'}';
                alert("stringify is -:"+tempdate);

                selectedDate=tempdate;
                jqxgriddata=data;
                $(this).datepicker("refresh");

                jQuery("#myGrid").setGridParam({ 'data':  data}).trigger("reloadGrid");

                alert('sucess!');

             },
             error:function(data,status,er) {
                 alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
             }
         });
```

i am using above code to refresh grid after server response but not success i am using jqx grid Server response is json array i am able to display grid at first time but not able to refresh it please help

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @anurupr no iam not getting any error

Comment: @anurupr i receive latest data from server but grid is not refresh

Comment: Are you getting alert `alert("parse json  - "+parsedJSON.length);`?

Comment: Read this http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/triggerreloadgrid-not-work/

Comment: @dfsq yes i got the lenght

Comment: @anurupr but i am using jqx grid